# Is there a Kestrel- or OWIN- related convention around exposing Program.IWebHost?

Tags: asp.net-core, mstest

In order to make my ASP.NET Core `Program` more testable, I prefer to expose `IWebHostBuilder` instead of the auto-generated `IWebHost`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Songhay.Feeds.Tests")]

namespace Songhay.Feeds
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = GetWebHostBuilder(args);
            builder.Build().Run();
        }

        internal static IWebHostBuilder GetWebHostBuilder(string[] args) => WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
}
```

Is there a reason why `IWebHost` is exposed by default? Did I just make the runtime lifetime of my code problematic?

By the way, from an old-school MSTEST perspective, my `TestInitialize` looks like this:

```
    [TestInitialize]
    public void InitializeTest()
    {
        var basePath = this.TestContext.ShouldGetBasePath(this.GetType());
        var builder = Program.GetWebHostBuilder(args: null);
        Assert.IsNotNull(builder, "The expected Web Host builder is not here.");

        builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((builderContext, configBuilder) =>
        {
            Assert.IsNotNull(builderContext, "The expected Web Host builder context is not here.");

            var env = builderContext.HostingEnvironment;
            Assert.IsNotNull(env, "The expected Hosting Environment is not here.");

            env.ContentRootPath = basePath;
            env.EnvironmentName = "Development";
            env.WebRootPath = $"{basePath}{Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}wwwroot";
        });

        this._server = new TestServer(builder);
        Assert.IsNotNull(this._server, "The expected test server is not here.");
    }
```

Comment: The existing pattern is to facilitate tooling, not testing. EF tooling uses GetWebHostBuilder to resolve configuration and services.